# Feed Elasticsearch from Hive in real or near real-time

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, hive

Let me describe the idea of pipeline I am planning to build.

1. Twitter data coming in and stored in HDFS in JSON format.
2. Create an external Hive table on top of JSON files using SerDe for some hive analytics.
3. Use Elasticsearch for indexing, real-time analytics and search. For that to create Hive external table using ES connector.
4. Feed as fast as possible Hive ES external table with data from Twitter table.

Is it feasible idea?

What I don't know is how to feed ES table with new data only. I understand I will need to create workflow with hive script and schedule it to run let's say every minute. But how I find just new data?

Or I just better off feeding data directly to ES and just creating Hive external table for hive analytics?

Comment: You should fork the work flow at the step before HDFS. You put into HDFS and ES at the same point. Maybe a step before that to parse and format the JSON data

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, I thought about this because I will use Apache NiFi but it doubles the storage.

Comment: How so? Unless I'm mistaken, the ES connector to Hive will read Hive data into ES, so the way you mentioned and my way are storing the same amount

Comment: I'm imagining this: Twitter to Kafka. Kafka to Logstash and Flume. Logstash to ES. Flume to HDFS.

Comment: @cricket_007 ES has it's own storage. So the same tweet will be stored in HDFS and ES.  Unless we feed ES only and Hive has an external table pointed to ES index.

Comment: Well, you said as fast as possible, so shoving your real time data into ES will provide that. Querying over Hive for real-time analytics is not going to be fast

Comment: @cricket_007 We don't need real time analytics from Hive. For internal use only. The idea is to store data in one place (HDFS). But looks like it's not feasible.

Comment: You can use ES to point it at Hive, sure. It just will not be quick for real time analytics on that particular index. Documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/hive.html

Comment: @cricket_007 Are you talking about this?


CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE json (data STRING)
STORED BY 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES('es.resource' = '...',
              'es.input.json` = 'yes');
...

Comment: Maybe I didn't read that page correctly, but no, that's an external Hive table that would query ES. Therefore, you'd feed data into ES instead of HDFS.

Comment: Will I be able to use [LOCATION hdfs_path] and  [PARTITIONED BY (col_name data_type [COMMENT col_comment], ...)]?

Comment: The table (or data) isn't stored on HDFS, as far as I know, so location shouldn't matter. Therefore partitioning doesn't make sense, and comments are just Metadata, so that might work. The only thing that creating the external table like that does is to give you SQL access to ES via Hive.

Comment: Well, this is an interesting experiment to try. Point this external table to HDFS and see if data will be indexed by ES.

Comment: What do you mean? I don't think the `STORED BY` option to elasticsearch allows you to place data in HDFS. It's a connector, not a transfer tool

Comment: I understand that. I think You are right. Adding file to HDFS will not mean that this file automatically written to the table.